# How does one integrate Haskell code into a C program?

Tags: gcc, ghc

Although there are a few tutorials on the web showing how to compile a C program utilizing Haskell functions, every tutorial compiles their C code with ghc. In the ``Real World'' C code files will be compiled using gcc.

My goal is to create .o files from Haskell code and then link them to the core C program. Below is a basic working example.

Fibonacci.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Fibonacci where
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci n = fibs !! n
    where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
fibonacci_hs = fromIntegral . fibonacci . fromIntegral
foreign export ccall fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
```

test.c:

```
#include "Fibonacci_stub.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);
    i = fibonacci_hs(42);
    printf("Fibonacci: %d\n", i);
    hs_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: test 
test: Fibonacci.o test.o  
    gcc -shared Fibonacci.o test.o -o test 
test.o: test.c
    gcc -c -I/usr/lib/ghc/include test.c 
Fibonacci.o: Fibonacci.hs
    ghc -c -O Fibonacci.hs
clean:
    rm *.o *.hi test *_stub.h
```

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14826353/fibonacci.tgz

When running make, first: the ghc compiler will generate a Fibonacci_stub.h and a Fibonacci.o file. Second: the gcc compiler will generate the test.o file from the test.c file. Lastly the gcc compiler should link the .o files and generate the executable.

Instead this error is provided:

> /usr/bin/ld: Fibonacci.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `base_GHCziBase_plusInt_closure' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value

The output says to use -fPIC, I've tried to place it in several places, but these attempts have not been fruitful in eliminating the error.

1. Where should I place -fPIC in the Makefile?
2. Is the -fPIC suggestion useful? Are there obvious deficits in the Makefile its self, which would prevent compilation?

Answer (score 2):

I've been faced similar issue trying to put ghc's .o into shared library and realized that ghc just ignores -fPIC without immediate -shared flag (so your suggestion is correct). For detailed discussion see this [link](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3705). The ticket by link marked as «solved», but nothing actually changed in ghc command lines since 2009. Briefly speaking, the reason of that behaviour lies in ghc implementation and only proposed solution is to build a separate shared library from Haskell code.

Comment: Alternatively, since the OP doesn't seem to need a shared object, he might try simply removing the `-shared` from `gcc -shared Fibonacci.o test.o -o test`.